# How do I add corresponding dates to a single column of values in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a single column vector dataframe like so:

```
m <- matrix(sample(c(1:10), 400, replace = TRUE))
d <- as.data.frame(m)
```

I want to add another column to the dataframe on the left hand side with dates corresponding to each value. So for example, if I wanted to specify the date range be between 8th September 2020 and 13th September 2021. Then I want the resulting dataframe to look something like this:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-09-09 | x |
| 2020-09-10 | y |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-10-13 | z |

How could I achieve this?

Comment: How do you know which value corresponds to each date?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the values I actually have in my dataframe are ordered. In the above example I have randomly generated values simply to demonstrate what the vector column looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

m <- matrix(sample(c(1:10), 400, replace = TRUE))
d <- as.data.frame(m)

d %>% 
  mutate(Date=seq(ymd("2021-09-09"),by="days",length.out=400), .before=V1)
```